# cmake flags for opengl using glew and glfw

Tags: opengl, cmake, glew, glfw

I have this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[] )
{
    if( !glfwInit() ){
        fprintf( stderr, "failed\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and in my CmakeLists.txt:

```
PROJECT(test C)
find_package(OpenGL)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(
    -std=c99
    -lGL
    -lGLU
    -lGLEW
    -lglfw
)
SET(SRC test)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test ${SRC})
```

running "cmake ." doesn't produce any error, but running make will says:

```
test.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tut1] Error 1
```

while running:

```
gcc -o test test.c -std=c99 -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lglfw
```

successfully compiles the code without error. How do i make cmake run with my code?

also, if i add these lines to the main function:

```
glfwOpenWindowHint( GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4 );
glfwOpenWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
glfwOpenWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 1 );
glfwOpenWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
```

even running gcc with the same flags will produce error:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:14: error: ‘GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:14: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:14: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:15: error: ‘GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:16: error: ‘GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:16: error: ‘GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

i'm running linux mint based on kubuntu 10.04, cmake v2.8, libglfw-dev, libglfw2, libglew1.5, libglew1.5-dev, glew-utils.

I'm new to cmake, glew and glfw. Thanks for your help guys!

cheers!

P

Answer (score 4):

you can see here an example how I use cmake with glfw.
http://code.google.com/p/assembly3d/source/browse/tools/viewer/CMakeLists.txt

I use FindGLFW.cmake for finding glfw
http://code.google.com/p/assembly3d/source/browse/tools/viewer/cmake_modules/FindGLFW.cmake

Also, glfw version in ubuntu is 2.6.
GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR and GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR just works in glfw 2.7 and I think OpenGL 3.x works only with glfw 2.7.

Best

Answer (score 3):

To see the commands that the CMake generated makefile is executing, run make as:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

Seeing the commands is very helpful when debugging CMake projects.  For the example provided, the following commands are executed:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -std=c99 -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lglfw -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.c.o -c test.c
/usr/bin/gcc CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.o -o test -rdynamic
```

The makefiles generated by CMake will compile each source file into an object file (this is what *gcc -c* does) individually, and then link all of the object files together with a separate command.  With the provided example, the OpenGL related libraries are being specified during the compilation stage, and not during the link stage.  Instead of specifying the libraries with **add_definitions**, the **target_link_libraries** command should be used.

A CMakeLists.txt file like this should work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test C)
add_definitions(-std=c99)
set(SRC test.c)
add_executable(test ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(test GL GLU GLEW glfw)
```

The *-l* prefix does not need to be specified for the libraries because **target_link_libraries** will automatically add the *-l* prefix for UNIX/Linux environments and the *.lib* extension for Windows environments.  More information about **target_link_libraries** can be found at [http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Pixar has did it yet. The below is its source code, you can refer it:
https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/OpenSubdiv/blob/master/cmake/FindGLFW.cmake